# Replace text in specific position in line with system date

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with a single line. I want to replace the text between positions 188 (inclusive) to 197 with the system date (YYYY-MM-DD).

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
sed  's/\(.\{188\}\)\([0-9-]\{10\}\)\(.*\)/\1$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')\188/g'
```

I want to use sed or anything else that works in a shell script.

The input file is:

```
{ "agent": { "run_as_user": "root" }, "logs": { "logs_collected": { "files": { "collect_list": [ { "file_path": "/home/ec2-user/logs/**", "log_group_name": "Staging", "log_stream_name": "2020-10-24", "timestamp_format": "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]" } ] } } } }
```

. . . and in the output, I want to change only the the date as shown below.

```
{ "agent": { "run_as_user": "root" }, "logs": { "logs_collected": { "files": { "collect_list": [ { "file_path": "/home/ec2-user/logs/**", "log_group_name": "Staging", "log_stream_name": "2020-10-25", "timestamp_format": "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]" } ] } } } }
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for your feedback. Viewed the earlier answers and accepted them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written as per shown attempts of OP in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d) '{print substr($0,1,187) date substr($0,198)}' Input_file
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a generic script that finds all occurrences of dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD and replaces them with the system date?

Comment: @AmitGupta, yeah we could do so you could search here you may get threads related to it